# Is it possible to add multiple commands to the readline .inputrc file?

Tags: macos, unix, readline

I'm trying to configure my Terminal and I would like to insert **@{}** at one key-stroke. This works with the following code

```
# .inputrc
"\e\"": "@{}"
```

But I also want the cursor to end up inside the braces. How can I do this? The following doesn't work.

```
# .inputrc
"\e\"": "@{}": backward-char
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
"\e\"": "@{}\e[D"
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you. Where did you find the char code for the left arrow?

Comment: If you type CTRl-V in the terminal it will display the escape code for the next key you type.

Answer (score 0):

My immediate way to fix your overall goal (not really answering your question, but hopefully helping you anyway): write a bash alias or function for it. grev() perhaps, or something similar - at least, this is what I would do were I in your situation.

I am interested to see if what you originally asked is possible, however, so voting up your question in hopes that you can get a 'real answer'!